# Detecting static resources in tween

Tags: pyramid

I am writing a tween and I need to know if the request is for static resource (add_static_view) or not. I don't want to set session cookie on static assets, as this would prevent caching them. What would be good way to find out or clear the set-cookie header in response processing for static assets?

Example::

```
class ReferralCookieTweenFactory:
    """Tween to capture referral links and """
    def __init__(self, handler, registry):
        self.handler = handler
        self.registry = registry

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.method == "GET":
            # We are only interested in incoming links with a referrer
            q_name = config.get_query_parameter_name(self.registry)
            ref = request.GET.get(q_name, None)

            # TODO: detect static resources here and bail out, as we don't want to 
            # do any sessions when the user is accessing static resources

            # We capture only the first referrer
            if not "referral" in request.session:
                # XXX create a session
                # set cookie, etc.

        response = self.handler(request)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path prefix for your static resources just check if `request.path_info` matches the route for static resources.

For production environment do not serve static resources with your wsgi server at all and leave this task to your http server like nginx/apache instead.